# reset return value of a function python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

So, I have a function that is going to return a lot of variables like this, that function will count how many conditions that is true, if in the Number column  starts with ‘S’ and in the Anti column is smaller than 7 days will return True and count for example 5 with that condition:

```
def Count ():
 sql_con_obj = SqlConnector()
 sql_con_obj.connect()
 sql_con_obj.con.commit()
 sql="SELECT * FROM bd_opensgc.teste"
 df= pandas.read_sql_query(sql,sql_con_obj.con)
 
 Smaller=df["Anti"] < to_timedelta(7,unit="D")
 Between = ( to_timedelta(7, unit= "D") < df["Antig"] ) & ( 
 df["Anti"] < to_timedelta(25, unit= "D") )
 Bigger=df["Anti"] > to_timedelta(25,unit="D")
 S = ['S']
 SSmaller = df['Number'].str.startswith(tuple(S)) & Smaller
 SBetween = df['Number'].str.startswith(tuple(S)) & Between
 SBigger = df['Number'].str.startswith(tuple(S)) & Bigger
 SumSmaller = sum(Smaller)
 SumBetween = sum(SBetween)
 SumBigger = sum(SBigger)
return SumSmaller, SumBetween, SumBigger
```

in my code I will be calling this function in another one that will send a email with the values imported from Count, like so:

```
def sendemail ():
    SumSmaller, SumBetween, SumBigger = Count()  
    wrkbk = load_workbook("excel.xlsx")
    sh = wrkbk.active
    nlines=(sh.max_row) - 1
    cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cfg.read('config.ini')
    me = cfg.get('EMAIL', 'sender', vars=os.environ) 
    password = cfg.get('EMAIL', 'password', vars=os.environ) 
    server = cfg.get('EMAIL', 'server', vars=os.environ)
    you = cfg.get('EMAIL', 'reception', vars=os.environ)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = me
    msg['To'] =you
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
    msg['Subject'] = str(nlines) + " Pedidos de alteração de conteudo de release no EASYVISTA"
    text="{}\n{}\n{}".format(SumSmaller, SumBetween, SumBigger)
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open("excel.xlsx", "rb").read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="excel.xlsx"')
    msg.attach(part)
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
   
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login(me,password)
    smtp.sendmail(me,you.split(','),msg.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
```

The next code is not how my code works but is a example, I’m making a loop with while true with another function and inside that function is the sendemail(), but I think like this works just fine and gives me the same problem.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 while True:
  if condition= True:
   x=threading.Thread(target=sendemail)
  
  if condition = True:
   x=threading.Thread(target=sendemail)
  time.sleep(20)
```

I am looping that sendemail function, in the first loop the SumSmaller, SumBetween, SumBigger gives me the return value that I need and sends a correct email but in the next loop, the values will duplicate... Is there a way to reset the return values of the function in the "sendemail" function after it makes Count like this?

```
def sendemail ():
    SumSmaller, SumBetween, SumBigger= Count ()
    #Reset values of function Count
```

To note that the loop passes throw the first and then the other condition!

Comment: Your `sendemail()` function does nothing with the return values and they are lost when it returns. Also your example loop code never exits the first `while` loop.

Comment: If I make the assumption that `Count()` accesses a database and returns the same values each time, then yes your email will contain duplicates. Under what circumstances do you expect the return values to change?

Comment: Im not creating a thread in the function sendemail, that thread will have instead another function that extracts and insers into the database when it runs and then at the bottom have the sendemail() function to iniciate, the condition its to define a time, if its 8:30 will rum condicion 1 and if its 14 will run condition 2